# Does Morphia honor java.persistence annotations?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Does Morphia honor `javax.persistence` annotations? I have a scenario where I need to publish a light weight object model with minimal dependencies, and then have separate modules choose how it performs it's persistence using this common object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not unfortunately.  Most of those annotations wouldn't apply to morphia models anyway so it might be more confusing than it's worth.

Comment: That does make sense. But, here's a thought. I scanned a handful of production applications that I work on and use Morphia. The most common annotations are Entity, Id, Embedded, Index, PrePersist and Version. This is a subset of the persistence annotations. So, wouldn't it be nice to support at least these (along with the existing morphia ones), and tie up the behaviors? And, document that?